# How to get different price from selected Date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different price (PriceA and PriceB) to select from different date (DateA and DateB). PriceA is valid at the end of March and PriceB is valid from 1st April. How should i get PriceA from DateA and PriceB and DateB accordingly. I had PriceA and PriceB in db from different column.

Comment: Add table structure

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to show  price based on date, you can use `CASE WHEN`

```
select CASE WHEN date < '2017-04-01' THEN PriceA else PriceB end as price FROM tbl
```